# Trouble reading from text file with IDs on each line

Tags: java, file, text

I have a text file called "q.txt" that I would like to read from, and based on the ID (primary key), I would like to select the string associated with it. 
e.g. `0014,<Random string here>`

So far I have created a method to obtain the #### ID. Now I need to scan through the file and find the corresponding string and output it to a textview.

The problems I have run into are FileNotFoundException and IOException. So where do I put the text file so i DO NOT need to add a whole path (eg D:\Projects\...\q.txt), but just "q.txt"?

And how do I run through the file so that a random question can be picked?

I also need this to be dynamic if an array is used.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in your code. You could place the file in the same directory as your main `.java` file.

Comment: i have no code other than the randomID() method. I have tried multiple ways of reading and outputing lines from file and have tried and failed, so i deleted those lines.

Comment: Show us all of your code, even your **previous attempts**. We can't help if you don't **try** and provide us with a starting point to go off of.

Comment: Sounds to me like some sort of Homework-Help. Edit your question and paste your code with a specific error. Otherwise i think you wouldn't get qualified answers hiere

Comment: You have several questions, I advise you to ask separate questions separately in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your file has this as it's contents:

`id,question`

```
0001,Some Question?
....
0014,Foo Bar?
...
9999,Last question?
```

Then you have to parse each line of the file into two separate fields. One to store the id and the other to store the question. You are already getting a random id with your `randomID()` method, so in your `onClick()` method, call the `randomID()` to get the random id and pass it to your `loadDatabase()` method to search the file for that random id. *Take a note that the random id must exist in your file*.

Once you find the random id, set the question to the `TextView`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    String id = randomID();
    loadDataBase(id);
}

public String randomID() {//generates an ID for the next question ####
    String id;
    int questionID;
    int challenge;
    Random ran = new Random();

    int randomChallenge = ran.nextInt(5);

    if (randomChallenge == 0) {
        challenge = 2;
        questionID = ran.nextInt(12);
    } else {
        challenge = 0;
        questionID = ran.nextInt(103);
    }
    id = Integer.toString(challenge) + String.format("%03d", questionID);

    return id;
}

public void loadDatabase(String id) {
    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("q.txt"));

        while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            String lineParsed = br.readLine().split(',');
            if(lineParsed[0] == id) {
                someTextView.setText(lineParsed[1]);
            }
        }
        br.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found: " e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
1. for the path of the file.

```
String basePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();//this will get the path of the class of your program.
try{
BufferedReader strReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(basePath+"\\nameOfYourFile.extension"));//this will find your file
}catch(FileNotFoundException | IOException e){
//e
}
```

2. If your wanna pick a random of the lines:

```
String str=null;
int rng=(int)(Math.random()*NumberOfTheLinesInYourFile);//generate a random number
for(int i =0; i<rng;i++){
str=strReader.readLine();//pick the line at rng variable;
}
System.out.println(srt);
```

output:
1 random line of the file